# Google Map Big Markers inaccuracy on tap

Tags: java, android, dictionary, sdk, markers

I am facing a problem while i am developing an application Using Google maps SDK.

I am creating dynamically some markers on the map, but these markers are quite big (using custom marker image and label above them).

But when i try to tap on a specific marker many times it selects the very next to it.

The accuracy of the click is not perfect and more over some times i need to click twice in order to get the click event get fired.

Making a google search i found that there are some issues with google maps sdk markers.

Is the issue being caused because of the size of the markers?

Answer (score 0):

You can you marker options like this.

```
MarkerOptions lMarkerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Title")
            .draggable(true)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .position(YourLatLng)
            .snippet("Title");
```

It will use default marker with whatever color you want.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not use default marker style, but i have to use a much bigger marker with custom png icon and title above